# real spectrum clarification

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T: X\to X$ be a bounded operator on the real Banach space $X$.Does the spectrum of $T$ consist of the  reals in the spectrum of its complexification?Or are they the same thing by definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is invertible, then so is $T'$: indeed, if $ST=TS=I$, then 
$$
S'T'(x+iy)=STx+iSTy=x+iy.
$$
Conversely, if $KT'=T'K=I$, then define an operator $S$ on $X$ by $Sx=K(x+i0)$. Then
$$
STx=K(Tx+iT0)=KT'(x+i0)=x+i0.
$$
In both cases the induced inverse is bounded by the Open Mapping Theorem.

It follows that if $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, then $T-\lambda I$ is invertible if and only if $T'-\lambda I$ is invertible; so
$$
\sigma(T')\cap \mathbb R=\sigma(T). 
$$